# Getting Illustrator to send true black to Ricoh printer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, black

My Illustrator design shows "rich black" but when I send it to my Ricoh Aficio GX e3300n printer the black comes out dark maroon/brown.

Comment: Are you trying to print a CMYK image?  I think that printer is only designed to print RGB images.

Comment: Is it also set to export as Rich Black (not just *show* rich black)?

Comment: What is the formula of the rich black?

Answer (score 0):

That printer has quite comprehensive driver setting guidance. Seemingly Mac driver has much less control than Win driver. See a screenshot of the manual:

[image]

If you are Win user, be sure that K is used for black in your image and printer settings.

BTW the proper "rich black" mixture is different for different print processes.